# Teenage girl falls through portal into an alternate reality with only her backpack

Tags: story-identification, parallel-universe

Looking for a book I read as a kid, from the 80s/early 90s. Young teenage girl falls through portal of scientist she works for while cleaning up. Finds herself in alternate reality with only her school backpack. Possibly with horses or horse like creatures. She stuns the “natives” with things like orange soda etc. It might have been a series?